# Помогите разобраться. Дана структура с полями char и int

Tags: c++, структуры-данных

у меня вопрос нужно ли освобождать память, я создал динамический массив Name? Спасибо за понимание.

List.h

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma once    
struct Listnode 
{
    char *name;         
    int age;            
    Listnode *next;     
    Listnode(char *Name, int Age, Listnode *Next)
        :name(Name), age(Age), next(Next) {}
};

class List
{   
    Listnode *head = nullptr;
public:
    void push(char *name, int age);
    void show();
};
```

List.ccp

```
#include "List.h"

//добавление в начало.
void List::push(char *name, int age)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        head = new Listnode(name, age, head);
    else
        head = new Listnode(name, age, head);
}

void List::show()
{
    Listnode *ptr = head;

    while (ptr) {
        std::cout << ptr->name << ' ' << ptr->age << std::endl;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Main.ccp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"

int menu();
void enter(List &a);
void show(List &a);

int main()
{
    setlocale(NULL, "RUS");

    List A;
    char choice;

    for (;;) {
        choice = menu();
        switch (choice) {
        case 'e':
        {
            enter(A);
            break;
        }
        case 's':
        {
            show(A);
            break;
        }
        case 'q': return 0;
        }
    }   
}

int menu()
{
    char ch;

    do {
        std::cout << "(E)nter of data\n";
        std::cout << "(S)how of data\n";
        std::cout << "(Q)uit\n";
        std::cin >> ch;
    } while (!strchr("esq", tolower(ch)));

    return tolower(ch);
}

void enter(List &a)
{
    char name[30];
    std::cout << "Введите имя: ";
    std::cin >> name;

    char *Name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    strcpy(Name, name);

    int age;
    std::cout << "Введите возраст: ";
    std::cin >> age;

    a.push(Name, age);
}

void show(List &a)
{
    a.show();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду, нужно ли вам удалять динамический массив `Name` в функции `enter`, то нет, не нужно, так как указатель на этот массив вы заносите в узел списка.

Другое дело, что вам следует написать деструктор списка, который будет удалять все узлы и в том числе и память, адресуемую указателями, которые определены в узлах.

Comment: Спасибо, немного понял. Ещё вопрос я могу написать функцию которая будет, например, сортировать по int или по char

Comment: @Ilya Почему бы и нет?

Comment: С точки зрения корректности я правильно написал код или где-то можно написать по другому?

Comment: вы вместо `enter` написали `nteer` я Вас правильно понял?

Comment: @Ilya Это опечатка.

Comment: Я написал функцию удаления с начала 
`void List::del()
{
 Listnode *first = head;
 head = head->next;
 delete(first);
 head = head;
}` 
Это функция удаляет 1-ый элемент, но правильно ли я сделал и освобождает ли она память на указатель в узле, я не знаю.

Comment: @Ilya Функция не верная.

Comment: Я должен освободить память на `name` + удалить сам узел?

Comment: а сейчас 
`void List::del()
{
 if (head == NULL)
  return;
 else {
  Listnode *first = head;
  head = head->next;
  delete(first->name);
  delete(first);
  head = head;
 }
}`
это тоже неправильная?) Как не страна но программа работает

Comment: @Ilya Сейчас лучше, только последнее предложение не имеет смысла.

Comment: Она и в 1-ом варианте тоже работала. Там есть утечка памяти как я понял

Comment: я написал 2 функции которые сортируют по `char` и по `int`, но у них разные имена. Может посоветуете как перегрузить функцию для `char` и `int`

Comment: @Ilya Если у вас есть вопросы, то задавайте их отдельными вопросами на сайте. Комментарии предназначены лишь комментировать вопросы и ответы.